Is there a conflict with Isaiah if the correct meaning / translation of 'alam' (ō·w·lām) עוֹלָֽם׃ is forever/everlasting?
Is forever / everlasting until the end or for a period or different depending on the context, for example when talking about God?  I’m trying to work out if the English translation is correct or misleading.
If it does mean forever or everlasting would there not be a conflcit with Isaiah 32:14 & 15?
Isaiah 32 (would forever cause a conflict in this passage)
14 For the palace will be forsaken, the busy city abandoned. The hill and the watchtower will become caves forever (‘aḏ ‘ō-w-lām) -the delight of wild donkeys and a pasture for flocks—
15 until the Spirit is poured out upon us from on high. Then the desert will be an orchard, and the orchard will seem like a forest.
Genesis 17:13 Whether they are born in your household or purchased, they must be circumcised. My covenant in your flesh will be an everlasting covenant (‘ō-w-lām).

I'm sorry I don't understand the title of the question. What's the difference between forever and everlasting?

It is also discussed here https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/145502/36610.

@Dov I have edited the heading and Q, trying to work out if the English translation is correct if it means forever / everlasting or for a period

Edited again - clarification of a possible conflict in Isaiah 32:14 & 15

The root עלם means to hide, conceal as discussed here. Strictly speaking, עוֹלַם means hidden uknown time of existence, which got revealed due to some bad or good actions. For example, Pinchas received בְּרִ֖ית כְּהֻנַּ֣ת עוֹלָ֑ם (Bamidbar 25:13). I.e. because of his good act he created an existence in time of kehuna for himself and his offspring. In the passuk Isaiah 32:14 the words עַד־עוֹלָ֔ם mean that due to bad acts of women, the populated areas would be abandoned, i.e. that abandonment would be created in time for that part of the world. No time in the Torah is "forever", since we can say only about G-d היה, and הוה and יהיה. Translations of the word עוֹלָ֔ם as "world", "forever" certainly diminish the full Hebrew meaning.

Many thanks very helpful
